# How does one make a child panel fill the remaining space in a parent panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got two panels (panel1 and panel2) inside a main panel. Panel1 is set to DockStyle.Top and panel2 is set to DockStyle.Fill.  I would assume that panel2 would fill the remaining space left after panel1 but instead it just fills the whole of the main panel and panel1 sits over panel2.

How do I get panel2 to just fill the remaining space after panel1 is set to DockStyle.Top without them overlapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Panel2 use anchors in all ways.

Answer (score 4):

Set panel2's dock to Fill, then change the order the controls are loaded via either Bring To Front, or Send To Back. This will alter which area panel2 fills.